# Can't import pyplot in python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I've installed `matplotlib` with pacman in archlinux

```
> $ pacman -Q python-matplotlib                                                                                              
python-matplotlib 3.3.0-1
```

But when I enter python

```
> $ python                                                                                                                   
Python 3.8.3 (default, May 17 2020, 18:15:42) 
[GCC 10.1.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

then and run `import matplotlib.pyplot`

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I got this error message:

```
Python 3.8.3 (default, May 17 2020, 18:15:42) 
[GCC 10.1.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 36, in <module>
    import matplotlib.colorbar
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py", line 44, in <module>
    import matplotlib.contour as contour
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/contour.py", line 17, in <module>
    import matplotlib.text as text
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .textpath import TextPath  # Unused, but imported by others.
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/textpath.py", line 11, in <module>
    from matplotlib.mathtext import MathTextParser
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/mathtext.py", line 27, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
```

Does anyone encounter this problem?

How to solve it?

Comment: `pip install pillow`

Comment: Hi @bigbounty: thanks! it's OK. please post it to answer.

Comment: Posted as answer.

Comment: So, Does pyplot need the `pillow` package?

Comment: Yes, see the dependencies section - https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/users/installing.html

Comment: Ok, I got it. Please also add `see the dependencies section - matplotlib.org/3.3.0/users/installing.html ` into your answer :)

Comment: Added to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install `pillow` library because it's a dependency for `matplotlib`. Refer the dependencies section - https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/users/installing.html

`pip install pillow`

Comment: If matplotlib was installed using `pacman` it would be better to als use that to install pillow, e.g. `pacman -S python-pillow`.

Comment: I read official package information about `python-matplotlib`. `python-pillow` is *optional dependency* for `python-matplotlib`.